# ASP.Net Web Api Url.Link not returning a UriString in unit test

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I Have the following test:

```
[Test]
public void Add_New_Group_Should_Return_StatusCode_Created_And_A_Header_Location_To_The_New_Group()
{
    var newGroup = new GroupData { ID = 1, UserID = 1, Name = "Group 1", Description = "Description 1" };

    var fakeGroupDAL = A.Fake<IGroupDAL>();
    var contactGroupsController = new ContactGroupsController(fakeGroupDAL);
    SetupControllerForTests(contactGroupsController, HttpMethod.Post);

    var response = contactGroupsController.AddGroup(new ContactGroupApiRequest(), newGroup);

    Assert.IsTrue(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created, "Should have returned HttpStatusCode.Created");

}
```

Which calls the following configuration method:

```
private static void SetupControllerForTests(ApiController controller, HttpMethod httpMethod)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, "http://localhost/contactgroups");

    var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ContactGroupsApi", "{controller}/{action}/{request}", new { request = RouteParameter.Optional });
    var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "contactgroups" } });


    controller.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
    controller.Request = request;
    controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
}
```

I'm trying to test the following action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddGroup([FromUri]ApiRequest req, [FromBody] GroupData contactGroup)
{

    if(ModelState.IsValid && contactGroup !=null)
    {
        _groupDal.AddGroup(contactGroup);

        contactGroup.Name = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(String.Format("{0} - {1}", contactGroup.Name, contactGroup.Description));

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created) { Content = new StringContent(contactGroup.Name) };

        var uriString = Url.Link("ContactGroupsApi", new { controller = "contactgroups", action = "Group",  UserId = contactGroup.UserID, GroupId = contactGroup.ID});

        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uriString);

        return response;
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

The action method works perfectly well when called normally, but fails under test because the call to Url.Link returns null.

```
var uriString = Url.Link("ContactGroupsApi", new { controller = "contactgroups", action = "Group",  UserId = contactGroup.UserID, GroupId = contactGroup.ID});
```

All this code is based very closely on the following article: [Unit test ASP.NET Web Api](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/16/unit-testing-asp-dot-net-web-api/)

I suspect that when running under test there is insufficient route table info. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I fixed my tests by adding the HttpRouteData to the HttpRouteDataKey property of the controller's HttpRequestMessage. Like this:

```
controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] = routeData;
```

Comment: Thanks JDM, I would never have thought of that

Comment: Although when I look back at the original article. The solution is mentioned in the comments, just never saw it. DOH!!!

Comment: Been looking all over for this!

Comment: If you upgrade to API 2 and MVC 5 it does not work anymore. The Url object is still null

Comment: If you're using Web API 2 or MVC 5, you'll need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659257/unit-test-with-route-data-not-working-on-asp-net-mvc-5-web-api