# Unit Test with route data not working on ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have upgraded my web api project to the latest version, using MVC 5
The application runs properly but this line of code is not working anymore on my unit tests:

```
string uri = this.Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = savedOrganization.Id });
```

The Url property of the controller is now null.
This is how I configure the mock controller:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://xxx/api/organization");
var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary {{"controller", "organization"}});

controller.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
controller.Request = request;
controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] = routeData;
```

Before upgrading to MVC 5 it was working fine.

When I debug the test it shows that the Url property is now null
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like in MVC 5 the Url property is created in a different way.
I have introduced this line in my tests and now the Url property is back to normal

```
private static void SetupControllerForTests(ApiController controller)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://api.clientele-itsm.com/api/organization");
    var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
    var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"id", Guid.Empty},
        {"controller", "organization"}
    });
    controller.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(request);
    controller.Request = request;
    controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
    controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] = routeData;
    /// inject a fake helper
    controller.Url = urlHelper;
}
```